# Get Data from Angular ngRedux-Store

Tags: angularjs, angular, redux

I would like to load data from ngRedux-store and react to changes. I want to use this one in a guard using the CanActivate interface.

Usually I retrieve the data like this

```
@select(['auth', 'IsAuth']) isAuth : boolean;
```

but I can't use that in my guard class. I guess I'll have to do something like that.

```
console.warn('AuthGuard#canActivate called');
var d = this.ngRedux.select(['auth', 'IsAuth']);
console.error(d);
```

I get only a annonymusSubject. But i want to get my boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work

```
this.ngRedux.select(['auth', 'Header']).subscribe(m => {
        this.Header = m;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `take` operator to get the first value from your select and complete the observable

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    // returns true/false from the store so canActivate 
    // can determine if the user can navigate to the route
    return this.ngRedux.select(['auth', 'IsAuth'])
        .take(1);
}
```

Comment: I get a error."TypeError: this.ngRedux.select(...).take is not a function". I add import 'rxjs/add/operator/take' to my file and now i get the same annonymusSubject.

Comment: I, now i understand your posting, but i need the data instandly to work togther with them.

Comment: @Taladan So basically you need to dispatch an action before this to make the `IsAuth` boolean available when this select runs?